# UITableView contentInset changes

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have set the contentInset of the tableView in the method`- (void)viewDidLoad` and the property is`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(200, 0, 200, 0);`
however ,`tableView.contentInset`  will be changed automaticly to :`{64, 0, 0, 0}`
.Why this happened, and how can I slove this problem?

Environment: XCode8.1 iOS10.1

```
    #import "YAVideoViewController.h"
static NSString * const ID = @"cell";
@interface YAVideoViewController ()

@end

@implementation YAVideoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor arcColor];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:ID];

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(200, 0, 200, 0);
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 50;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"第%ld个cell",indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need change the content inset in viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(200, 0, 200, 0);
}
```

Comment: can we do it from the storyboard? if yes, how?

Answer (score 5):

Add this in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: The same can be unchecked in ViewController's attribute inspector.